# Can I Install a Salesforce Package, that is dependent on another package, without installing the dependent Package?

Tags: package, package-install, package-dependency

I'm fairly new to Salesforce. I've created a package, say **OMI**. The Package **OMI** is dependent on the package **LTI**. For some reason, I can't install **LTI** (**LTI** is in development). Can I just install **OMI** package? I don't care if it works. I just want to install it.

Any leads/workarounds would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By dependent if you mean your **OMI** package has any references (class, page, components etc) to **LTI**, then **NO**. Compilation has to happen properly before a package gets installed.

If the package does not compile properly it would fail to install.

Check [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_install_pkg_sample_script.htm) one to install packages with dependencies, if using SFDX.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. one more thing, can i DEPLOY my `force-app` to my scratch developer edition organisation? because whenever I do, it gives me the error.

referenceTo value of 'xyz__c' does not resolve to a valid sObject type.

Comment: what is the meaning of `force-app`, does it have any reference to the above two packages you mentioned, if yes then you need to get those dependent packages installed , https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_install_pkg_sample_script.htm, only then you can install yours in your scratch org.

Comment: yes, actually 'force-app' contains all the source code for the **OMI** package, which depends on **LTI** package (Sobjects). My scratch developer org doesn't contain **LTI** package and I'm trying to deploy the **OMI** package. Basically I'm trying to find a workaround to deploy **OMI** (depends on **LTI**) without having to install **LTI**, if that's even possible. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot deploy metadata that has dependencies without first installing those dependencies. As Nagendra Singh said.

Comment: Thank you for your help.